# Accessing MVC5 Attribute routing parameter in a custom attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes, attributerouting

I'm having a bit of trouble with a WebAPI project using MVC5 and attribute routing.

Essentially, this is what I want to do:

```
[Route("Products/{CategoryId}")]
[ClaimsAuthorize([{CategoryId}], ClaimsEnum.CanViewProducts)]
public Products Get(){
  ...
}
```

Where [{CategoryId}] is where I want to pass the CategoryId to the attribute handler.  The CustomAttribute handler looks like this:

```
public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string CategoryId, params ClaimsEnum[] requiredClaimTypes)
```

Where ClaimsAuthorize is a custom attribute overriding the Authorize attribute.

How can I access the CategoryId parameter from the custom attribute?  Is this possible?  Or is there another way of passing it to the attribute handler?

This is pseudocode, but describes my problem.  I need to know the category that is passed with the request URL when I'm processing the authorization.  I know I can use headers, but I want to keep things visible in the URL if I can.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this approach:

[ProtectedController]

```
[Route("Products/{CategoryId}")]
[ClaimsAuthorize(ClaimsEnum.CanViewProducts)]
public Products Get(){
  ...
}
```

ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute.cs

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
_categoryId = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["CategoryId"].ToString();
```